# If Statement, Not Working

Tags: php, html

Ok, so i'm trying to get this if/else statement to work with out this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE
```

Here is my if/else statement:

```
<?if ($stats -> totalReferrals($odb, $_SESSION['username']) == '10' or > '10');
  {?>
  <h4><strong>Total Referrals: <font color="green">
<?php echo $stats -> totalReferrals($odb, $_SESSION['username']); ?>
</font></strong></h4>
<?}else{?>
 <h4><strong>Total Referrals: <font color="red">
<?php echo $stats -> totalReferrals($odb, $_SESSION['username']); ?>
</font></strong></h4>
}?>
```

If you can help me...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: use some good source code editor it will point out the syntax mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
 if ($stats -> totalReferrals($odb, $_SESSION['username']) >= '10')
```

and **mainly** remove that `;` after the if condition.It terminates the if condition there itself.Now the code should be like

```
<?php if( $stats->totalReferrals($odb, $_SESSION['username']) >= '10') { ?>
    <h4><strong>Total Referrals: 
          <font color="green">
              <?php echo $stats->totalReferrals($odb, $_SESSION['username']); ?>
          </font>
        </strong>
    </h4>
<?php } else { ?>
    <h4><strong>Total Referrals: 
          <font color="red">
              <?php echo $stats->totalReferrals($odb, $_SESSION['username']); ?>
          </font>
        </strong>
    </h4>
 <?php } ?>
```

Keep this syntax...even you didnt put php at starting tag and didnt gave any space for `}?>`

Comment: hmmm... now its giving me this error:
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end`

Comment: ok well now i guess i get: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'`

on the 195 = `} else {?>`

Comment: acctually i got it!, thanks for all your help! i'll make yours the answer, since it helped.

Answer (score 0):

in if statement change to
       this >= that
it will work !
and delete ; after if statement !